# ASP.NET MVC Anti Forgery Token is not one-time (per request) token?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've read a lot of articles and made some own tests and what I can see from my tests **and** source code ([IsCookieTokenValid and GenerateCookieToken](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.WebPages/Helpers/AntiXsrf/TokenValidator.cs) - you can see there hard coded  `IsSessionToken = true`) that ASP.NET Anti Forgery Token is per session, not per request (or POST request and so on). So token stored in the cookie remain the same during user's session. **But** token on the form changes (it's new) with every request (page refresh).

I've check if form submit with old **form** tokens are still valid, and they are. So what's the point to generate every time new form token if old tokes still valid and token in the cookie remains the same during the user's session?

I don't see in the code any setting to change this behavior and make token "one-time". The only option or solution is to delete the cookie and that will force to generate the new one. Correct? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up modifying ASP.NET MVC library and added setting `GenerateOnetimeToken` to `AntiForgeryConfig` to be able generate new pair of tokens (cookie and form tokens) with every page request (AntiForgeryToken() helper call).

[Here is ASP.NET MVC 5 branch for this change.](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/Kitsula/AntiForgeryToken)